# Discrete log for prime powers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, discrete-optimization

I was fiddling around and found that a function of the form $$L_b (x)=\left(\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{x^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right) \mod p^k$$ seems to behave similarly to a discrete logarithm modulo $p^k$ (explained below), assuming $p \nmid x$, $p \nmid b$, and $p^{k+1} \nmid b^{\phi(p^k)}-1$.

For example, if $p^k=9$ and $b=2$, then $L_2(2)=1, L_2(4)=2, L_2(8)=3$.

However, there seems to be some errors, such as (with the same modulus) $L_2 (16)=7$, when its discrete logarithm is actually $4$

---

To clarify what I meant by having properties similar to a discrete logarithm:

Proposition 1. $L_b (xy)=L_b (x) + L_b (y)$, for $x$ and $y$ coprime to $p^k$.
$\underline{Proof}$: Let $\phi (n)$ be Euler's Totient function.  Then
$$(x^{\phi (p^k)}-1)(y^{\phi (p^k)}-1) \equiv 0 \mod p^{2k} \Rightarrow$$
$$(xy)^{\phi (p^k)}-1 \equiv (x^{\phi (p^k)}-1)+(y^{\phi (p^k)}-1) \mod p^{2k} \Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{(xy)^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k} \equiv \frac{x^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}+\frac{y^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k} \mod p^k \Rightarrow$$
$$L_b (xy) \equiv L_b (x) + L_b (y) \mod p^k$$

Note that in the last step, we multiplied by $\left(\frac{b^{\phi(p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1}$.  Admittedly, $\phi$ could be replaced with Carmichael's function, and I believe it would still work.

Proposition 2. If $x=b^r$ for residue $r \mod p^k$, then $L_b (x)=r \mod p^k$.
$\underline{Proof}$: We have the following $$L_b (x)=\left(\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{x^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k} \right)=\\\left(\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{(b^r)^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k} \right)=\\ \left(\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}+\frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k}+\dots \frac{b^{\phi (p^k)}-1}{p^k} \right)=\\ 1+1+ \dots +1 \equiv r \mod p^k$$

However, due to the previously mentioned errors, I must have made some sort of mistake.

**If someone could look this over, explain the mistake and possibly suggest a better modified function, it would be much appreciated**

Comment: When $p^k=3^2$, $L_2(x)=0, 1, 80\frac{8}{9}, 455,…$ for $x=1, 2, 3, 4,…$, so I feel sure I must be missing something (a modulo reduction perhaps?). Or my mental arithmetic isn't what it was.

Comment: @MartinKochanski Sorry, the arithmetic of the fractions happens in integers, but the arithmetic of the -1 exponent happens modulo $p^k$, and the arithmetic of the $\phi (p^k)$ exponents happen modulo $p^{2k}$.  Also, even with this correction, I remember finding some errors, and I was hoping for an explanation of that as well.

Comment: Re "Proposition 2", as far as I know $a^{pr}-1=(a^p-1)(a^{p(r-1)}+a^{p(r-2)}+..+a^p+1)$, how do you arrive to that conclusion from $\frac{(b^r)^{\phi(p^k)}-1}{p^k}$?

And re the definition, the part saying $p^{k+1} \nmid b^{\phi(n)}-1$, where is $n$ coming from?

Comment: @rtybase Ah thank you for commenting!  In Prop 2, the sum is implied by the property proven in Prop 1.  Thank you for catching that $\phi(n)$.  It came from an earlier draft of the question.

Comment: I see a problem : $\frac{2^2-1}{3} = 1$ while $\frac{(2-3)^2-1}{3} = 0 \ne 1 \bmod 2$, so how $f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{3}$ can be a discrete logarithm $\bmod 3$ if $f(x) \not\equiv f(x+3) \bmod 2$ ?

Comment: and an explicit formula for the discrete log is given [there](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/107463) and [there](http://math.ucdenver.edu/graduate/thesis/dreiff.pdf)

Comment: @user1952009 Well as I mentioned, the function has errors and I was hoping for an explanation.  The example you gave is a bit more obvious why it has an error.  The problem I have is that those explicit formulas you gave are not computationally efficient for large primes or prime powers.  This formula can be made efficient with modular exponentiation.

Comment: @user1952009 Also, since your example gave $0$, it does not satisfy the $p^{k+1}\nmid b^{\phi(p^k)}-1$ criteria I gave.

Comment: @user1952009 The criteria I stated is just a guarantee that $\frac{b^{\phi(p^k)}-1}{p^k}$ _has_ an inverse in order to put it into the formula for $L_b (x)$.

I had lists for $p=3, 5, 7,\ldots$ etc back when I first thought of the problem, but I have since lost those lists.  It wouldn't take long to reconstruct it, but I haven't gotten around to it.  

Since this formula can be computed rather quickly, it seems to indicate that the formula _could_ be fairly simple and easy to compute (possibly with a modified version of my function), but that's just my intuition.

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, I misread your question.  I don't use $f(x)=\frac{x^{p-1}-1}{p}$ because it may not be scaled correctly.  Notice how in Prop 2, the $\left(\frac{b^{\phi(p^k)}-1}{p^k}\right)^{-1}$ scales the function down to just $1$'s

Answer (score 1):

for $p$ prime and $gcd(x,p) = 1$ let $$f(x) = \frac{x^{p-1}-1}{p}$$

by Fermat theorem $x^{p-1}-1 = k p,y^{p-1}-1 = m p$ so $(x^{p-1}-1)(y^{p-1}-1) = kmp^2$ i.e.
$$\frac{(x^{p-1}-1)(y^{p-1}-1)}{p} \equiv \frac{(xy)^{p-1}-x^{p-1}-y^{p-1}+1}{p}\equiv 0 \bmod p$$
$$\implies f(xy) \equiv f(x)+f(y) \bmod p$$

**but this is not a discrete logarithm modulo $p$**

for the simple reason that a discrete logarithm modulo $p$ fulfills :

$$g(xy) \equiv g(x)+g(y) \bmod p-1$$
since the discrete logarithm is a group isomorphism $$((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*,\times) \quad \to \quad \ (\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z},+)$$

Comment: Yes I know this, hence the errors we both mentioned.  What I'm asking about is if my function can be modified to sort out the errors we encountered; to turn it into a true discrete logarithm.

Comment: @JasonM no, the point of my answer is that your function fulffils $f(xy) \equiv f(x)+f(y) \bmod p$ instead of $f(xy) \equiv f(x)+f(y) \bmod p-1$, so it has nothing to do with a discrete logarithm modulo $p$

Comment: @JasonM so your mistake is that you looked at $L_b(x) \bmod p$ instead of $L_b(x)\bmod p-1$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed your point the first time, but I don't see how this rules out a relationship to a discrete logarithm.  The $\mod p$ is precisely what gives $L_b$ its pseudo-additive properties.  To phrase my question in your notation, is there a way to modify my function so that $L_b (x) \mod p-1$ is a discrete logarithm?

Comment: @JasonM no. your function doesn't even depend on $x \bmod p$ : $L_b(x+p)$ is unrelated to $L_b(x)$

Comment: I haven't stated it yet, but in my own investigations I have taken note of this; namely $L_b$ may not be a well-defined function for inputs from $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$, and so couldn't have a domain of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$.  But I remain unconvinced that this guarantees **no** relationship exists between this function and the discrete logarithm.

Comment: @JasonM try with $p =3$, you'll see that $h(xy) = h(x)+h(y) \bmod 3$ is an obstruction for it being a discrete logarithm modulo $3$. and $\phi(n)$ is never prime, so it can't be a discrete logarithm modulo $n$ for any $n$.

Comment: @JasonM : but this is another question. You can open a new one if you want : is a function satisfying $L(xy) \equiv L(x)+L(y) \bmod p$ (example $L(x) = C \frac{x^p-1}{p}$) useful for something ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not seem relevant to the question.  I'm **not** asking for a prime $p$ such that $L_b$ is a discrete logarithm.  I'm **not** asking for the errors to eventually disappear.  I'm asking for a thorough explanation of why the errors occur (differing moduli has already been noted), and any suggestions for a modification.  If you believe it cannot be modified into a better function, then I need something more than examples

Comment: @JasonM come on I just did : you looked at $L(x) \bmod p$ instead of $L(x) \bmod p-1$, it is clear and simple

Comment: @JasonM by definition a group morphism $(Z_p,\times) \to (Z_{p-1},+)$ has to fulfill $L(xy) \equiv L(x)+L(y) \bmod p-1$. that's clear and simple

Comment: @JasonM and I cannot prove you can't modifiy it in something useful, I just proved it is not related to the discrete logarithm (your question was : "where is my mistake, when I'm proving that it is a discrete logarithm)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can think of extending this function to have codomain $\mathbb{Z}_{p(p-1)}$, and then restricting it back down to a function with codomain $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$.  Perhaps there is a way of doing this that perserves additivity.  Of course that's a very vague strategy, and I will have to give it some more thought.  Nonetheless, I truly do appreciate the insight you've given, so you get a +1

Comment: @JasonM I think it deserves a new question : are the functions $L_n(xy) \equiv L_n(x)+L_n(y) \bmod n$ useful for something ?

Comment: Sure if you think so, but since it is about additive functions in general, it's more difficult for me to relate it back to my specific function.  My function is _pseudo_-additive since (for example) $L_2 (2 \cdot 8) \neq L_2(2)+L_2(8) \mod 9$.