# Solve $19^n$ = $801777482$ $\pmod {4535332489}$ given $4535332489$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

Solve $19^n$ = $801777482$ $\pmod {4535332489}$ given $4535332489$ is prime and without calculating any factors of $4535332488$. Is solving this possible with the current information? If so, what is $n$. Thanks for solvers.

Comment: What you are asking for is the discrete logarithm base $19$ of $801777482$ modulo the given prime. (It certainly exists as $19$ is a primitive root for that prime.) Computing discrete logs is not a cheap problem, but for the number of that size it is certainly feasible. It's unclear what you actually want to know.

Comment: Then there is a solution $n$ $19^n$ = $801777482$ $\pmod {4535332489}$, but given $19$ is a primitive root $4535332489$ only verifies that $n$ exists, but does not reveal $n$. (I didn't expect anyone to compute factors of $4535332488$, and verify $19$ is a primitive root  of $4535332489$ however.)

Comment: Yes, one would have to compute it. There are any number of methods to compute discrete logarithms. What do you want to do with that number anyways? If you'd ask for an explanation of methods to find it  that be a reasonable question. The value itself is not.

Comment: Now we can find $n$ which I do not know how other than manually computing $19^n$ $\pmod {4535332489}$, for all $n$ < $4535332489$. Please let me know of a shortcut.

Comment: Are we allowed (desirous of) factoring 801777482 ?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm the section algorithms.

Comment: It may or may not reduce it to something simpler.

Comment: You could factor $801477482$ (which I do not know), but not $4535332488$ which would give that $19$ is a primitive root of $4535332489$.

Comment: facoring 8014777482 didn't help. less you can solve $19^n = 2$ and $19^n = 11$ and $19^n = 36444431$ so... no...

Comment: Why "without factoring $p-1$" (where is $p$ is your prime modulus)? What is the background of this problem, to explain why you want us to solve with one arm tied behind our back?

Comment: For larger primes $p$ (say 300 digits) factoring $p-1$ is extremely hard, so when I do have a larger modulus $p$, $a^n$ $=$ $d$ $\pmod p$ can still be found

Comment: What work have you done on this problem? Apparently none, hence my close vote.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms

Comment: When you have to do a 300-digit prime, you may find you are out of luck. There are cryptographic systems which depend for their security on the computational infeasibility of solving precisely this kind of problem. If you do find a way to solve it, you may attract a lot of unwanted attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $n = 971428210$ which may be computed with the Baby Step Giant Step algorithm.  And that doesn't require factoring $p-1$. But it can't be done by hand, since two lists of length > 60,000 must be computed.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  Test it out in this link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=570e7445d8bdb334c7128de82b81fc13

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong number. Now it's fixed. Thanks for checking.

Comment: No problem.  Do you think you could look at my problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819331/discrete-log-for-prime-powers

I tried using it to solve this problem, but I couldn't figure out the mistake